# Powershell Script Truncated Result

Tags: powershell

I have the following script,

```
$filteracl = {$_.IdentityReference -match "User" -and ($_.FileSystemRights -band 131241 -or $_.FileSystemRights -band 278)}
$objects = Get-ChildItem "C:\" -Recurse -Force
foreach ($i in $objects)
{
$i.GetAccessControl().Access | Where $filteracl  | Select `
                                @{n="Path";e={$i.fullname}},
                                @{n="User";e={$_.IdentityReference}},
                                @{n="Permission";e={$_.FileSystemRights}}
}
```

However, the output from the path is being truncated. I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: if this is for interactive session, pipe the `Select` result to `Out-GridView`, e.g. `Select ... | Out-GridView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Format-Table -Wrap` like:

```
$filteracl = {$_.IdentityReference -match "User" -and ($_.FileSystemRights -band 131241 -or $_.FileSystemRights -band 278)}
$objects = Get-ChildItem "C:\" -Recurse -Force
foreach ($i in $objects)
{
$i.GetAccessControl().Access | Where $filteracl  | Select `
                                @{n="Path";e={$i.fullname}},
                                @{n="User";e={$_.IdentityReference}},
                                @{n="Permission";e={$_.FileSystemRights}} |
                                Format-Table -Wrap 
}
```

Since the whole statement is in a loop and `Format-Table` displays headers, so you'll see multiple headers. To get rid of that you can edit your script to store the output in an Array and then finally display when the loop is complete. Something like:

```
$filteracl = {$_.IdentityReference -match "User" -and ($_.FileSystemRights -band 131241 -or $_.FileSystemRights -band 278)}
$objects = Get-ChildItem "C:\" -Recurse -Force
$OutputView = @()
foreach ($i in $objects)
{
    $s = $i.GetAccessControl().Access | Where $filteracl
    $output = New-Object PSObject
    $output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Path" -Value $i.fullname
    $output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "User" -Value $s.IdentityReference
    $output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Permission" -Value $s.FileSystemRights
    $OutputView += $output
}

$global:outputView | 
Select-Object Path,User,Permission
```

Comment: ok great. Now because this script was not written by myself and I have totally no clue about powershell scripting, could you suggest a way on how I could remove the repeated headers? For for every line there will be Path  User  Permission as the header, is it possible to only have this on the first line?